# Unable to get this Python code up and running

Tags: python

thank you for taking the time out to answer this question. i just started learning python and I am stumped here.

This is the code:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
x = 'a'
y = '3'
z = x + y
print ('Hey')
print ('whats your age buddy')
d = raw_input(int)
print (d)
If ( d > 22 )
print('good to go')
Else
print('get out')
```

And here is what I get:

> C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/untitled/Test.py
>   2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>
> Hey
>
> whats your age buddy
>
> 5
>
> 5
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/untitled/Test.py", line 10, in 
>   If ( d > 22 )
>
> NameError: name 'If' is not defined
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Please Help!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: BTW, `raw_input(int)` doesn't do what you think. That function always returns a string.

Comment: If you "just started learning" and are "stumped," the solution is to _continue learning_, not toss a few lines together and ask someone to fix it.

Comment: For everyone who seems to be offended by the fact that this questions is very basic: I am a tech writer by profession. I have had exposure to coding but not much and not to python. I find myself in a situation when I must learn the language quickly and in limited timeframe each day, alongside a full time electrical engineering degree and a full time writing job. I am sorry if I offended you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Solution fix and "mentoring" below:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
x = 'a'
y = '3'
z = x + y
d = str(raw_input('Hey\nWhats your age buddy? '))
e = int(d)
print (e)
if (e > 22):
    print('good to go')
else:
    print ('get out')
```

Couple things:

1. Can't stand when people downvote and offer absolutely no help or direction to become better for the next time you have to ask a question. So learn from this, don't get bummed out with "Why the heck are they downvoting?" and focus on learning. There is always a place for teaching those who want to learn.
2. Not sure what `x`, `y` or `z` or the `sys.version` have to do with any of your problems. Did you mean to have them implemented somehow?
3. You have several syntax problems, I correct and detail below.

Since you are using `raw_input` I am going to assume you have a Python 2.x version. Python 2.x built in function `int()` is what you want `d` to be. Alternatively, you don't have to have it as a `integer` but you could compare `strings`; however lets go the `integer` route.

I broke this section off because its not the subject of your problem:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
x = 'a'
y = '3'
z = x + y
```

However, we can do cleaner things here:

1. Lets clean up your IO (input/output):

Instead of:

```
print ('Hey')
print ('whats your age buddy')
d = raw_input(int)
print (d)
```

Do this:

```
d = str(raw_input('Hey\nWhats your age buddy? '))
e = int(d)
print (e)
```

This makes `d` a `str` or `string` and uses the Python 2.x `raw_input` to get that string. The `\n` is the `new line` method and simply puts the second part of that single line command on the next line. It is just less code!

Assuming you keep `d` as numbers only, using `int(d)` converts your `string` to and `integer` for your `if/else` conditions below.

2. Lets correct the conditions:

Instead of:

```
If ( d > 22 )
print('good to go')
Else
print('get out')
```

Do this:

```
if (e > 22):
    print('good to go')
else:
    print ('get out')
```

Now your condition compares an `integer` (i.e. the `e`) to another `integer` (i.e. the 22). Python also requires that you have a `:` at the end of each `if`, `elif` or `else` before moving onto your statements.

Also, work on indentation so you can know what code is nested under what!

Comment: Thank you so much. The x, y, z and sys were just to get a feel of the language.  I had spent a couple of hours browsing the web before putting this question here. Again, thank you so much for taking the time to answer this. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just starting out python, I would recommend learning python 3 instead of python 2. Since python 3 is the present and future, while python 2 is the past and will not be further updated.

Your code will run if you do this:

```
d = int(raw_input('whats your age buddy'))
print(d)
if d > 22:
    print('good to go')
else:
    print('get out')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. :) I will definitely try this out, it does look like a much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

check your if statement:

the syntax is

```
if expression:
   statement(s)
else:
   statement(s)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

your if statement is wrong, as stated before.
it should be in the form:

```
if expression:
   do this
else:
   do this other thing
```

Your other problem is that you're using raw_input() wrong.The part that goes in the parentheses is the prefix of your input. For example:

```
s = raw_input('hello')
print s
```

would ask the user for an input, and prefix it with the word hello. An example of this program is this:

```
ryan
>>>helloryan
```